# How to save last record into the variable from select query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in sql server,write this query for select any data from table:

```
select   phoneNumber,sum(Duration) sumPrice
    from CDR
    where Date_>=@var1 and Time>@var2
    group by phoneNumber
```

up query return about 8 million record,i want save last record Time field into other variable,for example this:

```
select   phoneNumber,sum(Duration) sumPrice
from CDR
where Date_>=@var1 and Time>@var2
group by phoneNumber
@Time=last up query time column
```

how can i write that?thanks every body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set @Time = (Select Top 1 Time
  From CDR
  Where Date_>=@var1 and Time>@var2
  Order By Date_ Desc, Time Desc)
```

If you need to select more columns then you need to use:

```
Select Top 1 @Time=Time, Col1, Col2
From CDR
Where Date_>=@var1 and Time>@var2
Order By Date_ Desc, Time Desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Date Date,@Time Time  -- Assuming a Time field 

Select Top 1 @Date=Date_,@Time=Time
  From CDR
  Where Date_>=@var1 and Time>@var2
  Order By Date_ Desc, Time Desc

Select @Date,@Time
```